# How I generate qr code in django rest framework api

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, qr-code

- i want to make scannable qr code api
- generate qr code and put text inside qr code(offers)
- response in image format

`models.py`

```
....
qr_code = models.ImageField(upload_to='qr_codes', blank=True)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`models.py`

```
class ModelName(models.model):

    ....
    qr_code = models.ImageField(upload_to='qr_codes', blank=True)
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qrcode_img = qrcode.make("FLAT50") # FLAT50 is offer name, you can set your model's any field name using self.field_name
        canvas = Image.new('RGB', (290, 290), 'white')
        canvas.paste(qrcode_img)
        fname = f'qr_code-{self.coupon_code}.png'
        buffer = BytesIO()
        canvas.save(buffer,'PNG')
        self.qr_code.save(fname, File(buffer), save=False)
        canvas.close()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

`serializers.py`

```
class QRCodeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


class Meta:
    model = ModelName
    fields = ['..','..','qr_code','..']
```

`views.py`

```
class QRCodeAPIView(APIView):

serializer_class = QRCodeSerializer

def post(self, request):

    serializer = QRCodeSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response({
            'status' : True,
            'message' : 'Success',
            'Data' : serializer.data},
            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else :
        return Response({
            'status' : False,
            'message' : "Error"},
            status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

`urls.py`

```
    url(r'^add_data', QRCodeAPIView.as_view(), name='Create Data And Get QR'),
```

`response`

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Success",
    "Data": {
        "id": 1,
        ...
        ...    
        "qr_code": "http://192.168.1.24:8000/media/qr_codes/qr_code-FLAT50.png",
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: For the **File** in self.qr_code.save(fname, File(buffer), save=False) you can import it as:

`from django.core.files import File`